Stuck In sync serverless application? test event keep giving me timeout error. as well as postman
I hope the reader is doing well. I am currently stuck in this part. According to the video, it used to called:
"Deploy Serverless Application" but now it changes "Sync Serverless Application." So I followed exactly the way the video showed, but I encountered an error
Failed to create/update the stack: aws-pycharm-crud, An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: aws-pycharm-crud, An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
So I turn on the Auto Expand, when I "Sync Serverless Application". And then it works. Kind of.
My code is in my AWS, but when I try to test out API in Postman, it doesn't work. I keep getting 504 Gateway timeout error. Even when I create a test event in AWS lambda, I get the timeout error. I am not sure if the reason is I turn on the auto expand or if it could be a different reason.
I have done my own research, but I am quite stuck. When I create helloWorld project in pycharm and then "Sync Serverless Application", it worked fine. I am able to test AWS helloWorld Lambda function using the test event. I don't ran into any issues, except this one.
Also the function work, when I do run the configure: AWS local lambda in pycharm. But not remote.
It will be great help, if someone guide me or help me solve this issue. Thank you.
Edit: The issue has been resolved

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
